# Cannot import name 'S' sympy anaconda

Tags: python-3.x, anaconda, sympy, spyder

Hi all I am trying to user `solveset, S` as follows. However I receive error `ImportError: cannot import name 'S'`. Spyder could somehow recognize `S.` and suggesting available options for `S.xxxx`

```
def sub():
    ...
    from sympy.solvers import solveset, S #solve,
    from sympy.abc import x
    ....
```

Surprisingly I didn't see this error message discussion on www.stackoverflow.com.

I need to import `S` to confine symbolic variable `x` to `S.Reals` in the following circumstance.

```
sol = {1.50230320128349, 1.23749621150897 - 1.30203516616147*I, 1.23749621150897 + 1.30203516616147*I}
[i for i in sol  if np.isreal(sol) and i > 0]
```

However it leads to error:

```
TypeError: Invalid comparison of complex 1.23749621150897 - 1.30203516616147*I
```

Versions: Spyder 2.3.9 + Anaconda , Python 3.5 on Winx64.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`S` is not defined in `sympy.solvers` (it's in `sympy.core`). Just use `from sympy import S`.

Comment: Ho gosh! I missed so simple thing.   Thanks a ton.